# Why is my event listener not firing in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-5, laravel-events

So I am trying to log something simple when a new order is created in the laravel 5 application I am working on.

So I have a `OrderWasCreated` event which looks like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

use App\Order;

class OrderWasCreated extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $order;

    /**
     * OrderWasCreated constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }


    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

And then I have `OrderEventListener` which looks like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\OrderWasCreated;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class OrderEventListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function subscribe(Dispatcher $events)
    {
        $events->listen(
            'App\Events\OrderWasCreated',
            'App\Listeners\OrderEventListener@onOrderWasCreated'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  OrderWasCreated  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function onOrderWasCreated(OrderWasCreated $event)
    {
        \Log::info('Order was created event fired');
    }
}
```

In my `OrderController`, I have this in my store method somewhere:

```
    event(new OrderWasCreated($order));
```

Yet, when I am creating new orders, I don't see anything in my log file. What am I missing?

Comment: You have to register your event with a listener like https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#registering-events-and-listeners did you added a listener with your event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you haven't added `OrderEventListener` into `subscribe` property of `EventServiceProvider`, it should look like this:

```
protected $subscribe = [
   'App\Listeners\OrderEventListener',
];
```

If you added, please run `php artisan clear-compiled` to make sure your app uses current version of classes.

Comment: I was wondering if I am missing something small somewhere. Thank you.

Comment: php artisan clear-compiled and php artisan queue:restart are so important. 
easy-to-forget commands.

Comment: @SinanGül you saved the day! this is mentioned no where!

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple solutions off the internet. it was `php artisan event:cache` that solved it for me eventually!